# How to change the color of a DisplayObject when it moves in a specific zone?

Tags: flash, apache-flex

I am coding a graphical interface using Flex, and I have a qestion related to masks in Flash.

I want to create a kind of mask that defines which color and which alpha value a text will have according to its position on the screen. It is very easy to do that with the text being the mask of a bitmap, for instance.

However, I also want to take into account the color of the text itself.

For instance, if I create a red text, in some zone it will be red with a modified alpha value, but on another zone, the text will be full white, as if there was a kind of mask which also applies its own color on top of it.

Is there a way to easily do this kind of thing?

Of course, I can manually apply the format on the text according to where it is, but I wonder if there is an automatic processing like mask or blend mode using a DisplayObject as a processing pattern.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I would have states in my component that changes color, and have something be able to set those when your component rolls over your 'section'.

Comment: The thing is, the component does not have simple states (or, in my case, a simple set of colors). The color of the component can change on a gradient way, depending on where it is. For instance, I want it to be alpha 0 at the bottom ; if I move it on top, it will have alpha 1, with a gradient change between these two values ; but when the componant is in the middle, I want it to have another color.
I cannot do that with animations, as they are static components that I move with the keyboard, but not automatically.

Comment: Then you'll have to figure out a custom solution.  Maybe use the `UIComponent.move` event within your component, which then modifies whatever is needed depending on it's absolute position.

Comment: Is there no possibility to create a kind of mask that, instead of applying an alpha value to its underlying objects, applies a color value? It's disappointing, it would be useful, I think.

Comment: I guess you could.  You could add a layer with all those colors and then set the mask being that component that you move.  However, personally I find this solution to be the easy way out and a programed solution would be more robust.